# beam cross section modeling by extrusion on proe

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, modeling

I would like to create beam models having various cross sections on ProE tool.

Can I create a beam model like below by only extrusion?

[image]

Can anyone explain what is the best way to model various cross sections of beams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If pro-e is anything like solidworks then you need to draw a 2D version of the extrusion pattern. In your case, one large square with the 4 smaller squares within it.

Then select the area you wish to extrude and extrude it.

I recommend looking up some basic tutorials for ProE as I'm sure this would be covered in the early stages.

Comment: I have a question. After extrusion of all rectangular segments, all segments are automatically attached with each other?

Comment: If you extrude it all in one sketch as @ashgetstazered describes, all features will be attached to each other automatically.  You can also use separate sketches and extruded cuts for each of the holes.  If you do this, sketch them all on the face of the main beam to make them automatically attach to it, and so that they all reference the same sketch plane.